# Compare multiple records of normalized data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data of the following format for which I am trying to preform comparison using SQL:

The data are ratings of "groups" with up to 4 values rated per group:

**tblRatings**

| RatingID | GroupID | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2222 | 13 | 19 | (null) | (null) |
| 2 | 2222 | 13 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 3 | 2223 | 1 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 4 | 2223 | 1 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 5 | 2224 | 5 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 6 | 2225 | 10 | 12 | 13 | (null) |
| 7 | 2225 | 12 | 13 | 10 | (null) |

My goal is to compare the records and determine which GroupIDs have two ratings that match, with a match defined as the same list of values in any order, with all nulls to be ignored. Thus in the example data, GroupIDs 2223 and 2225 have a match, and the others do not.

How would you proceed to perform this comparison?

As a first step, I have used a union query to normalize the data to one value per row, as follows:

**qryRatingsNormalized**

| RatingID | GroupID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2222 | 13 |
| 1 | 2222 | 19 |
| 2 | 2222 | 13 |
| 3 | 2223 | 1 |
| 4 | 2223 | 1 |
| 5 | 2224 | 5 |
| 6 | 2225 | 10 |
| 6 | 2225 | 12 |
| 6 | 2225 | 13 |
| 7 | 2225 | 12 |
| 7 | 2225 | 13 |
| 7 | 2225 | 10 |

However I'm unsure how to proceed from there.

FYI, I am working in MS Access using tables linked in SQL Server.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Thanks @D-Shih, I am working in MS Access using tables linked in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't really kept up with the state of Access/Jet SQL but I'm fairly certain this is a valid query. My proposal is that you may be able to get away with matching on a set of aggregate values that stand in for matching the individual values.

```
select r1.RatingID, r2.RatingID, r1.GroupID
from
    (
    select
        GroupID, RatingID,
        count(Value) cnt, sum(Value) tot,
        avg(Value) avg, min(Value) as lst, max(Value) as grt,
        /* assumes no zeroes */
        floor(sum(log(Value+10)) * 100000) as lg
    from qryRatingsNormalized
    group by GroupID, RatingID
    ) r1
        inner join
    (
    select
        GroupID, RatingID,
        count(Value) cnt, sum(Value) tot,
        avg(Value) avg, min(Value) as lst, max(Value) as grt,
        floor(sum(log(Value+10)) * 100000) as lg
    from qryRatingsNormalized
    group by GroupID, RatingID
    ) r2 on     r2.GroupID = r1.GroupID and r2.RatingID > r1.RatingID
            and r2.cnt = r1.cnt and r2.lst = r1.lst and r2.grt = r1.grt
            and r2.tot = r1.tot and r2.avg = r1.avg and r2.lg = r1.lg
```

I've repeated the same subquery twice so perhaps want to just define that as a named Query/View and get this to work without the named subquery.

It's probably advantageous that your maximum is four values. The idea is that by comparing the total, product (via logarithm), average, count, minimum, and maximum you'll have an extremely high likelihood that the sets must be one and the same. It's pretty much like a checksum.

Some of this possibly hinges on whether you need to do this repeatedly or it's just a one-off, what the actual values are, how many total ratings/groups you've got, whether negative numbers are valid...

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=1b7b05c44d6935d43e54b012ebc0b486

Comment: Thank you @shawnt00, this approach worked for me. I took a similar tactic: I started with qryRatingsNormalized and then rather than a checksum, I did an exhaustive check via: (a) a Totals query grouping by GroupID and counting RatingIDs per Value, and then (b) a second Totals query taking the first Totals query as the input and grouping by GroupID and calculating the min of the count of RatingIDs. Thus a min of >=2 indicates the presence of a match.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set up a pass-through query with tsql to get around the Access limitations:

```
with r as (
    select GroupID, RatingID, val,
        row_number() over (partition by RatingID order by val) as rn,
        count(*) over (partition by RatingID) as cnt
    from tblRatings cross apply
        (values (Value1), (Value2), (Value3), (Value4)) as v (val)
    where val is not null
)
select r1.RatingID, r2.RatingID, min(r1.GroupID) as GroupID
from r r1 left outer join r r2 on
    r2.GroupID = r1.GroupID and r2.RatingID > r1.RatingID
    and r2.cnt = r1.cnt
    and r2.rn = r1.rn and r2.val = r1.val
group by r1.RatingID, r2.RatingID
having count(r2.val) = count(*) and count(*) = min(r2.cnt);
```

See working example here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=1b7b05c44d6935d43e54b012ebc0b486